# create a line chart with a defined logic

Tags: mysql

We have a set of data from an SQL query and we want to create a Line chart using that data.

```
SELECT REPLACE(req2.value,"Sprint 1", "sum") AS sprint  , SUM(val)  AS VALUE  FROM 
(SELECT issue AS iss,SUM(VALUE) AS val  FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD LIKE 'poin%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL AND issue IN ( SELECT issue FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD = 'sprint' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) GROUP BY VALUE,issue) req1 JOIN (SELECT issue,VALUE FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD LIKE 'sprint%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) req2
WHERE iss = req2.issue 

UNION ALL 

SELECT main2.value AS sprint  , SUM(val) AS VALUE  FROM 
( SELECT issue AS iss,SUM(VALUE) AS val  FROM dataissue,issue 
  WHERE FIELD LIKE 'poin%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND 
  VALUE IS NOT NULL AND issue IN ( SELECT issue FROM dataissue,issue 
                   WHERE FIELD = 'sprint' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) GROUP BY VALUE,issue) 
                   main1 JOIN (SELECT issue,VALUE FROM dataissue,issue 
                                WHERE FIELD LIKE 'sprint%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) main2
WHERE iss = main2.issue GROUP BY main2.value

ORDER BY  CAST(SUBSTRING(sprint,LOCATE(' ',sprint)+1) AS SIGNED)

-----------------------------------
|                        617,5   
   sprint1   |    52   |    565,5    |     
   Sprint 2      35         530,5
| 
|
```

The second column is not a calculated value (form the database)
the third one also 
the first row of the fourth column is a calculated value 
the logic is:

```
617,5 - 52 = 565,5
565,5 - 35 = 530,5 and so on
```

How to do we implement this logic using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sql to calculate cumulative subtract.

```
 SELECT  @prev_sets := t.sprint AS sprint,@prev_set := t.VALUE AS VALUE,
           ROUND(IF(0<@i,@i:=@i-t.VALUE , @i:=t.VALUE+@i),2) AS `VALUE`
FROM (


SELECT req2.value AS sprint  , SUM(val)  AS VALUE  FROM 
(SELECT issue AS iss,SUM(VALUE) AS val  FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD LIKE 'poin%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL AND issue IN ( SELECT issue FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD = 'sprint' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) GROUP BY VALUE,issue) req1 JOIN (SELECT issue,VALUE FROM dataissue,issue WHERE FIELD LIKE 'sprint%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) req2
WHERE iss = req2.issue 

UNION ALL 


SELECT main2.value AS sprint  , SUM(val) AS VALUE  FROM 
( SELECT issue AS iss,SUM(VALUE) AS val  FROM dataissue,issue 
  WHERE FIELD LIKE 'poin%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND 
  VALUE IS NOT NULL AND issue IN ( SELECT issue FROM dataissue,issue 
                   WHERE FIELD = 'sprint' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) GROUP BY VALUE,issue) 
                   main1 JOIN (SELECT issue,VALUE FROM dataissue,issue 
                                WHERE FIELD LIKE 'sprint%' AND dataissue.issue = issue.id AND VALUE IS NOT NULL ) main2
WHERE iss = main2.issue GROUP BY main2.value

ORDER BY  CAST(SUBSTRING(sprint,LOCATE(' ',sprint)+1) AS SIGNED)
)
t
                  JOIN (SELECT @prev_sets := NULL,@prev_set := NULL, @i := 0  ) i  

    ----------------------------------------------------
    sprint         |  value    |  cumulative_subtract  |
    ----------------------------------------------------
                   |           |        67.5           |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    sprint1        |   52      |        518.75         |
    ----------------------------------------------------
    sprint2        |   35      |         483.75        |
    ----------------------------------------------------
```

I think its will help you.

Thank you.